# Prove that the unit lower diagonal matrices $L, M$, and $D$ are all unique

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

> If all the leading principal submatrices of a matrix $A$ (i.e. all square submatrices that share a top left corner with $A$) are nonsingular, then prove that there are unique unit lower diagonal matrices $L$ and $M$, and a unique diagonal matrix $D$ such that $A=LDM^T$.

I've seen a proof that such matrices $L,D,M$ all exist, but I'm not sure how to prove uniqueness. I would start by assuming that there are two such matrices $L_1$ and $L_2$ and then derive a contradiction. I think I could then use a similar argument to show $M$ and $D$ are unique.

Here is the proof.

Factor $A=LU$. Define $D= diag(d_1,\cdots, d_n), d_i=u_{ii},1\leq i\leq n.$ All $d_i\neq 0$ as all of $A$'s leading principal submatrices are nonsingular. So $D^{-1}$ exists. Note that $D^{-1}U$ is unit upper triangular. So $M = (D^{-1}U)^T$ is unit lower triangular, and $A=LDM^T$.

Comment: The LU-factorization is unique if you require that elements on the diagonal of  $U$ are all equal to one, see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4138691/42969.